# Error 2003 (HY000): can't connect to MySQL server on ' IPv4 address' (10060)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud SQL Instance that I have been using for some time now and connecting successfully from MySQL Workbench.  However as of yesterday I can't connect using MySQL Workbench (or the command line on my laptop) and get the error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '207.xxx.xxx.xx' (10060)
```

I have done the following already:

- Authorised my laptop's IP address (found using whatismyip.com) in the Google Console.
- Assigned an IPv4 address to the database in the Google Console.
- Created new users and passwords to see if it was a user issue.  But that didn't help.
- Restarted the instance, restarted my home network/laptop and got new IP addresses (and updated the authorised IP address accordingly).
- Upgraded to the latest MySQL workbench 6.3 CE but still have the issue.

The database works as my app can connect to it and accesses the data, I just can't get a remote connection from my laptop.

I am new to this and am out of ideas on how to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is technically a better fit on the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) since it's not strictly programming related. That being said, have you probed the machine to be sure that port 3306 is open? Is connecting using SSH an option? That tends to be a lot more reliable.

Comment: Sorry my first post so not sure where to put it.  Also, for me its integral to my programming as I need to check that it's putting the right stuff in the DB and without a view of the DB I have no idea.

How would I probe the Google Cloud instance to confirm port 3306 is open?

Comment: Any port testing tool should do the job, but [nmap](http://nmap.org) is the most popular. If the port is open you're half way there. If it's closed or filtered you have a firewall issue. If you can use SSH try that first, it's a lot more reliable and doesn't depend on your physical IP address.

Comment: Is it possible something changed on the network to block port 3306? Do you have another network you could try on from your laptop?

Comment: @tadman can I move my question to the server fault community?  Or would I have to delete it and recreate it?

Comment: There's a status update on the Google Cloud Status page: "We are currently investigating issues with external connectivity for a very small number of Cloud SQL instances."

Comment: I also got the same error. But in my case, I have disabled the billing account and also stoped SQL instances. But the next day even I enabled the billing account for the project, the SQL  instance remained suspended. It takes some time to start the SQL instance again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.  After trying all of your suggestions I found a Google group and logged the [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-sql-discuss/sZuqLr62jII/EpKpimvwBgAJ).  Google have responded to it as follows:

> David Newgas: For now try connecting from a GCE instance (including cloud shell) or using a GCE instance to proxy connections from your laptop.
>   I have updated the dashboard with some more information (although it may take a while for you to see it due to caching)
>   To be clear, this issue will only be affecting first generation instances.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have enough 'points' to comment, so I'll have my say here.

I am having about exactly the same issue. About 10 days ago I connected fine to the Cloud SQL instance, and synced my db up. Yesterday I was going to push some updates etc. But I could not connect, even though I have changed nothing in respect to the database connection, except for the given IPv4.

I figured the issue was with my Django project, based on the App Engine Skeleton, so I created an issue on that project.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-django-skeleton/issues/16

Maybe/Hopefully some we get some information from there.

Comment: Thanks Martin that sounds very similar.  Let me know if you do get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
By pure luck I said "Let's try to connect with my local MySQL client while the gcloud command was saying

> "Whitelisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes..."

and (mysql local client) worked.